# apache symlinks and dokuwiki

Tags: symlink, apache-httpd

I am running a dokuwiki on an apache webserver. Usually I put media files into the directory /var/lib/dokuwiki/data/media. However, to be more flexible and to save disk space, it would be nice to use symbolic links instead of copying files to that directory.

Now my question is:

How to make apache to follow symlinks in the directory /var/lib/dokuwiki/data/media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [FollowSymLinks](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#options) is what you are looking for. First you have to locate the Apache configuration files. If you install Apache using your distro's package then they are more than likely to be in `/etc/apache2/` and the file you have to change is `httpd.conf`. If in your document root you have the symlink `wiki/media -> /real/wiki/media` then you will need to create a `Directory` section like this:

```
<Directory /wiki>
    Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory>
```

Please note that I am writing these from memory without any testing, so don't use these directions as is, consult the comments in the file, configuration guide for your distro and the Apache reference when in doubt.

Comment: Thanks! Could you describe more explicit what do do exactly for my case (put which lines in which files etc.) (I am an apache newbie - the server is only for my personal use)

Comment: @user5289 I updated the answer as requested.

Comment: I added: <Directory /var/lib/dokuwiki/data/media>
Options FollowSymLinks
</Directory> to my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf, and restarted apache, however it does not work.

Comment: Entries in Directory are relative to the document root of Apache, not the root of your filesystem. You should create a symlink in your Apache document root: `ln -s /var/lib/dokuwiki/data/media /var/www/wiki/media`, then go with `<Directory /wiki>Options FollowSymLinks</Directory>`

Comment: I tried your suggestion, however it didn't work. Note that there is already a file /etc/apache2/conf.d/dokuwiki.conf with contains: `Alias /dokuwiki /usr/share/dokuwiki/

<Directory /usr/share/dokuwiki/>
 Options +FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 order allow,deny
 allow from localhost 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.34
</Directory>` Futhermore /var/www/dokuwiki is a symbolic link to /usr/share/dokuwiki. Finally there is a link /usr/share/dokuwiki/data which points to /var/lib/dokuwiki/data.

Comment: That dokuwiki.conf looks correct. If there is an `Include` line in httpd.conf that include the dokuwiki.conf then you shouldn't have to make the changes yourself. Otherwise I don't know what is wrong here.

Comment: The missing point was that the directories the links point to should have execute permissions for others (I don't understand why, but it works now).

Comment: Ah, that was important. The execute bit on a directory determines if a person can do a ls in the directory. It is certainly needed.